# Is there any JS method that works like eval but also supports expressions like log(), ln(), sqrt etc

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a calulator from as my small react-native project and I was wondering if there is a JS function that has a method that works like eval but with more advanced expressions

Comment: `eval()` takes an arbitrary string and runs it as JS code. You have access to all JS functionality within that code including your own functions. Well, the scoping is a bit weird at times but you should have access to anything in local scope. With that said, `eval()` is *not* recommended for many reasons.

Comment: `eval()` can evaluate any piece of JavaScript code but you don't need `eval()` to write a calculator.

Comment: All those functions are in the `Math` object in JS: `Math.sqrt()`.

Comment: @Barmar Can you only pass a number to them ?

Comment: @m3k_1 Yes. What else would you want to pass to them?

Comment: ``eval(`with(Math) { ${input}; }`)`` but really you should write a proper calculator and not use `eval` to do calculations.